# Adding JavaScript/JQuery to single Wordpress Page

Tags: jquery, wordpress

So I have the following JQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $('.2s, .3s, .4s,.5s,.6s').hide();

    $('.leaderlist li').hover(function () {
        var takeClass = $(this).attr('class');
        $('.sliderdesc').hide();
        $('.' + takeClass + 's').show();
    });
});
```

I then added JQuery in the the functions.php of my theme with the following:

```
if (!is_admin()) add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "my_jquery_enqueue", 11);
function my_jquery_enqueue() {
   wp_deregister_script('jquery');
   wp_register_script('jquery', "http" . ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? "s" : "") . "://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js", false, null);
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
```

Finally, on the page itself I added this to the html editor as described on the wordpress help:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="launch.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
launch();</script>
```

However, the JQuery functions are not appearing on the page. How can I solve this?

Comment: You have no function `launch()`, so it cannot be called. Do the functions defined in the `launch.js` file work?

Comment: yes, the functions work within the launch.js file.